# pandas: assign to multiindex using .loc with mask

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, indexing, multi-index

Using the example from the [MultiIndex / advanced indexing: Using slicers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers) documentation.

```
def mklbl(prefix, n):
    return ["%s%s" % (prefix, i) for i in range(n)]


miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [mklbl("A", 4), mklbl("B", 2), mklbl("C", 4), mklbl("D", 2)]
)


micolumns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [("a", "foo"), ("a", "bar"), ("b", "foo"), ("b", "bah")],
    names=["lvl0", "lvl1"]
)


dfmi = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.arange(len(miindex) * len(micolumns)).reshape(
            (len(miindex), len(micolumns))
        ),
        index=miindex,
        columns=micolumns,
    )
    .sort_index()
    .sort_index(axis=1)
)
```

```
>>> dfmi
lvl0           a         b
lvl1         bar  foo  bah  foo
A0 B0 C0 D0    1    0    3    2
         D1    5    4    7    6
      C1 D0    9    8   11   10
         D1   13   12   15   14
      C2 D0   17   16   19   18
...          ...  ...  ...  ...
A3 B1 C1 D1  237  236  239  238
      C2 D0  241  240  243  242
         D1  245  244  247  246
      C3 D0  249  248  251  250
         D1  253  252  255  254

[64 rows x 4 columns]
```

In pseudo-code, what I want:

```
if D1/bar % 3 == 0 && D1/foo > 100:
    D0/bar = np.nan
```

Almost, but not quite there:

```
mask = ( (dfmi.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,:,:,"D1"], ("a","bar")] % 3 == 0)
       & (dfmi.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,:,:,"D1"], ("a","foo")] > 100))

dfmi.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,:,:,"D0",mask], ("a","bar")] = np.nan
```

The issue is that at any given index level either a mask or a selector can apply - bot not both. For example, I can apply the mask at a different level. That requires the mask to be generated with a full index (no missing values) or re-aligned to the original index. How (not excluding other approaches)?

---

*Later...*

I really thought this would work as the innermost index should have half the rows, but for some reason it raises a `ValueError`. Anyone know why?

```
>>> dfmi.swaplevel(0,3).loc[pd.IndexSlice["D0",:,:,mask.values], ("a","bar")] = np.nan
...
ValueError: cannot index with a boolean indexer that is not the same length as the index
```

While this does work, I thought there would be a cleaner way to change index values. I thought I'd used `index.set_levels` successfully in the past. Anyone care to fix this up?

```
t = mask.reset_index()
t["level_3"] = "D0"
t = t.set_index(list(t.columns.values[:4]))
mask = t.reindex(dfmi.index).fillna(False)
dfmi.loc[mask[0], ("a","bar")] = np.nan
```

Comment: That is the question.

Comment: kindly post the expected output; i'd like to test out my logic

Comment: Latest edit includes code to generate the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a temporary multiIndex `d0`:

```
d0 = dfmi.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,:,:,"D0"], ('a','bar')]
```

Next, use the boolean values from `mask`, combined with the [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) method, to get your nulls:

```
d0 = d0.mask(mask.array)
```

Update the original dataframe with `d0`:

```
dfmi.loc[d0.index, ('a', 'bar')] = d0
```

Comment: This works very well with my (more complicated) workflow; since neither `pd.mask` nor `pd.where` support an else condition, I replace the `d0.mask` with my else values: `else_df.mask(mask.array).values`.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to filter by the indices of rows that meet all criteria using numpy's [argwhere](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwji37Wyz-XvAhVFgf0HHTTLCK0QFjAAegQIBRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnumpy.org%2Fdoc%2Fstable%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.argwhere.html&usg=AOvVaw1GcGS8w3HHcXynIB2HQsOp) method.

For example:

```
is_D1 = np.array([index[-1] == "D1" for index in dfmi.index])
is_multiple_of_3 = np.array(dfmi.loc[:, ("a", "bar")] % 3 == 0)
is_greater_than_100 = np.array(dfmi.loc[:, ("a", "foo")] > 100)
mask = np.argwhere(is_D1 & is_multiple_of_3 & is_greater_than_100).flatten()
dfmi.iloc[mask - 1, dfmi.columns == ("a", "bar")] = np.nan
```

Comment: Nice. A little verbose. Couldn't you use my original mask, like `dfmi.iloc[mask.reset_index(drop=True).index[mask == True]*2, dfmi.columns == ("a","bar")] = np.nan`? The downside of this approach is you have to know the layout of the index.